# How i can add endpoint (or сatch a request and check its path) to BCL?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, base-class-library

I need to create a BCL that will automatically add a path to /api/environment, for example, in order to subsequently reuse this library by adding the same path to all projects that will do the same logic, for example, give the current environment of the application.

Initially I thought of doing this through middleware, or a minimal api, simply catching a specific request and processing it. But Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref is not available in BCL. Then I came to the conclusion that I needed to somehow catch the request, but I didn’t find a single library that would help me do this.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is ["middleware"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication)

Comment: "But Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref is not available in BCL" - are you looking for `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` ? you can use that in a library project (inside an `<ItemGroup>`) to indicate that you want the asp.net core bits

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen they already cited middleware

Comment: @MarcGravell Now I'll try to do it using your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in a class library and want access to the asp.net core bits, add a framework reference in the csproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```